# send two parameters to load a datatable via ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I'm working on a MVC4 C# App and for the moment it pass a parameter to a specific controller in order to populate a datatable (the jQuery plugin), the code is

```
$('#myTable').DataTable({
                searching: false,
                ...
                bAutoWidth: false,
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "/Home/CargarTabla?id=" + noDocumento,
                    "type": "GET",
                    "datatype": "json"
                },
```

but now I need to send two parameters and use this

```
"url": "/Home/CargarTabla?id=" + noDocumento + "&grupo=" + mensajero,
```

the value of mensajero is "hola"

```
var mensajero="hola";

        function cargarTabla() {
            $('#myTable').DataTable({
                ...
                bAutoWidth: false,
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "/Home/CargarTabla?id=" + noDocumento + "&grupo=" + mensajero,
                    "type": "GET",
                    "datatype": "json"
                },
```

the MVC controller receive the first value but doesn´t receive the second one, this is my controller

[image]

could you please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: the var mensajero is defined before the function that makes the ajax call, the value is "hola"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually sending the "undefined" string. If the parameter would not have binded, then grupo would have been null instead of "undefined".

The javascript code you have provided is probably truncated.
If you change the url in JavaScript code to this:

```
"url": "/Home/CargarTabla?id=" + noDocumento + "&grupo=testgroup",
```

and the parameter is retrieved in the Web API method, then, for sure, the way you pass mensajero variable is wrong.